# Complex Header with datatables

Tags: datatables

I am using a datatable FixedHeader extension without scrolling. 
Columns of complex header (header with rowspan and colspan) do not align properly. 
See pictures and codepen example.

[Pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WYSK.png)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    "paging": false,
    "ordering": false,
    "info": false,
    "searching": false,
     fixedHeader: {
     header: true,
     footer: true
     },
   });
 });
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/135679/pen/Gjdkzx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please give colum width for each cols. That will solve the issue.

```
<colgroup>
   <col width="20%" />
   <col width="15%" />
   <col width="15%" />
   <col width="15%" />
   <col width="15%" />
   <col width="15%" />
</colgroup>
```

Comment: Thank you Aneesh for the suggestion. It definitely works when the width of the viewport is about 1330 px or wider. On a narrower viewport the columns underneath a header spanning 3 cells are still misaligned.

Comment: Here is a new [codepen] that shows what I mean:(https://codepen.io/135679/pen/zKadJa)